# VueJS и Яндекс Share Api (блок “Поделиться”)

Tags: vue.js

Прикручиваю Яндекс Share Api (блок “Поделиться”) к vuejs проекту. Если добавляю в main.js, то при создании страницы кнопки соц сетей появляются, однако при переходе по роутеру элемент с кнопками не появляется.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import router from './routes'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import * as axios from 'axios'
import vuetify from './vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import "../src/assets/ya/es5-shims.min"
import "../src/assets/ya/share";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueResource)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    },
    error => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        console.log('Unauthorized, logging out ...');
        store.dispatch('signOut');
        // router.replace('/login');
        return Promise.reject(error)
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error.response);
      }
    });

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    router,
    store,
    vuetify
}).$mount('#app');

Ya.share2('hello', {
    content: {}});
```

Если же

```
    Ya.share2('hello', {
    content: {}});
```

определяю в компоненте использования (в created), то вообще ничего не появляется.
Может кто подсказать? 
Только начал изучать Vuejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покопавшись, разобрался, может кому пригодится.
Создал js файл с содержимым:

```
import "./lib/es5-shims.min"
import "./lib/share"

function yandex_shared(id) {
    new Ya.share2(id, {
        content: {},
        theme: {
            services: 'vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,twitter,lj,collections,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram',
            lang: 'ru',
            limit: 5,
            size: 'm',
            bare: false,
            popupDirection: 'bottom'
        }});
}

export default yandex_shared;
```

Далее импортирую в необходимый компонент и в hooks (created и updated) добавляю вызов функции, в которую передаю id необходимого компонента, как пример:

```
yandex_shared('social')
```

Всё работает у меня!